# JNA's W32API.* - where are they?

Tags: java, jna

I just downloaded both jna.jar and platform.jar (ver. 3.2.7) from http://java.net/projects/jna/downloads/directory/3.2.7 and according to http://jna.java.net/javadoc/platform/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/W32API.html I should find the W32API interface but I can't locate it.

Anyone can shed some light on this?
Thanks.

Best Regards, Joe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This class has been split up into Multiple classes in 3.2.7.
You can either revert to 3.2.5 to get the class as is, or, you can use these newer classes into which W32API has been split.

com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions  -->jna.jar

com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary --> jna.jar

com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef -->platform.jar

com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT  -->platform.jar